# Abandons on load() on some specific URLs

Tags: python, pyqt5

A very simple PyQt5 scraper. The following code print "success 1" without any issue, but "success 2" is not printed because when self.load (QUrl (URL) is called for the 2nd time, it abandons abnormally. No exception is caught. Is it a bug in PyQt5?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Render(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.html = None
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.page().toHtml(self._callable)

    def _callable(self, result):
        self.html = result
        self.app.quit()

URL = 'https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/canon-imageclass-mf269dw-monochrome-all-in-one-laser-printer/13466514'

Render(URL)
print('success 1')
Render(URL)
print('success 2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that not assigning the created object to variables causing a bad memory handling generating an *segmentation fault (core dumped)*:

```py
r1 = Render(URL)
print("success 1")
r2 = Render(URL)
print("success 2")
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  It works now. after the variables are assigned.  Thank you!

Comment: I modified the code slightly by adding a wrapper class.  Then load() function fails again on the 2nd time it is called.  The code is posted as a following up answer.  Did I make another mistake here?  Thank  you!